# Should I be reviewing questions/answers outside my skill set?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I am new to reviewing, but try to help out as much as I can. I mostly find myself reviewing questions about tools/frameworks/languages I have never used and have no experience with.

In these instances I find myself hitting the 'skip' button a lot and I am wondering if I am being too cautious.

When reviewing a question, part of what SO asks for, for something that *Looks OK* is:

> questions that can be found, understood and answered as-is

For me, or anyone, reviewing a question outside of their skill set, how can we know this? I can merely see if the question is understandable (even though the context escapes me), properly formatted and *seems* not overly broad. I feel like the line between *Looks OK* and *Requires Editing* depends greatly on the context.

Or should I just simply be looking for what I mentioned above; understandable (outside of context), proper formatting and specific?

Comment: Like with every question you review, you *use your judgement*.  Sometimes you don't need to know a particular language or library to see a questions is crap. Sometimes you do. Judgement helps you tell the two apart.

Comment: @Will good points, Will. That's very true, it's the grey area that usually has me hitting the 'skip' button, which I've learned is indeed the correct thing to do.

Comment: I wish we could filter reviews through tags. I often do end up hitting that skip button quite a bit.

Comment: @Ike that's a great suggestion, that would be awesome

Comment: Actually we can do that already! I didn't notice but there's a "filter" link in the corner of those reviews where we can put in tags.

Comment: @Ike not on triage reviews though :(

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Short answer: **no**. Use the "Skip" button judiciously until you find something in your area of expertise.

Longer answer...

Reviewing - like pretty much everything else on Stack Overflow - is an educational opportunity *if you choose to make it one*. You may not be able to learn enough to review *every* post accurately, but that doesn't mean you can't try; often, a little bit of research is all that it takes, and the knowledge you gain will serve you well in the future. Assuming you're starting out with some experience as a programmer, and one who has asked and answered questions on Stack Overflow, then you have a reasonable foundation upon which to build the necessary knowledge to evaluate a wide variety of posts in various topics, should you be willing to put the time and effort in to learn something about them...

...That said, there'll probably still be areas that still leave you cold. For example, I can't make head nor tails of [verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/verilog) questions. That Skip button is always your loyal friend.