# How can I review questions and answers properly?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues

In the review queues there are many questions and answers that are not related to my tags, so I am not able to properly review those posts. In these cases how can I review them in the proper manner? How can I see if these questions and answers are proper or not?

Comment: you van always *skip* a review to leave it to someone who has better knowledge on the topic

Comment: so i have to skip most of the questions ...is there anything to add my tags in review part.so i can get questions related to me..?

Comment: There is none, I think. I always wanted one as well

Comment: The fact that they aren't related to your tags doesn't necessarily mean you can't review them. Things like link-only answers and non-answers (*"has anyone solved this yet?"*) aren't domain-specific, for example. A complete absence of code or question/answer, or nonsensical writing, or terrible formatting; none of these depend on your knowledge of the technology they claim to be related to.

Comment: Which queue are you talking about? Most (all?) have the option to filter by tag. Look at the top, next to the queue name.

Comment: @Rob given the OP's rep, [first posts and late answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)

Comment: @Rob +1 I never saw that filter link there!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I be reviewing questions/answers outside my skill set?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310030/should-i-be-reviewing-questions-answers-outside-my-skill-set), but I would be remiss if I didn't mention the [FP/LA guide I started](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts) or the [general advice to use Skip early and often](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip).