# Understanding the review decisions of other users

Tags: support, feature-request, review-queues, review-history

I'm trying to help the community by reviewing via the various review queues. Sometimes, I am wrong, even if I only vote for languages and frameworks that I know. I see it when I am the only one to select a decision. So I'm searching why other users chose another decision so I can improve my understanding. When I don't know what to do, I click <kbd>Skip</kbd> button. I understood that this is the best solution for the community. But, sometimes, it's not helpful for me. I don't learn anything. I read this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310030/should-i-be-reviewing-questions-answers-outside-my-skill-set):

> You may not be able to learn enough to review every post accurately, but that doesn't mean you can't try; often, a little bit of research is all that it takes, and the knowledge you gain will serve you well in the future.

I agree and I think it could be useful for beginners to know what more experienced users answered. Currently, if I want to know what other users voted, the only solution is too "try, vote and look at the decisions of others". I don't think it is a good way to help the community.

So may I suggest adding a <kbd>I don't know</kbd> button?

For the community, it would work like the <kbd>Skip</kbd> button but it wouldn't count as a decision. The inexperienced user who clicked on it, would be able to review this question, but would be able to see what other users have chosen.

Comment: Honestly knowing the consensus in any review could make it more confusing as the 3 or 4 people who do the same review may make the wrong decision (happens more than you'd think).

Comment: @RobertLongson, when I click the Skip button, I don't see what everyone else chose. (Perhaps have I not enough reputation point.)

Comment: I usually click Skip and then Back on by browser, or bookmark the review before clicking Skip if I want to visit it later. When you look at a review you've already done something with, it shows the result, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: When I click Skip and come back, I can answer. But I was about to answer No at the RobertLongson question, but I didn't never show the `show skipped reviews` at the bottom of the page. So yes, thank you for your help @RobertLongson.

Comment: see also: [Can our Review History also list the items we have skipped?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221134/165773) at MSE

Comment: If you have questions about a particular review and are genuinely interested in hearing how other experienced reviewers would have handled it, you can ask in the chat room [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). Naturally, respect the forum: don't spam with a whole bunch of "what about this?" posts. And I would recommend only asking for feedback after you've personally Skipped, to avoid biasing your specific votes.

Comment: Thank you, very much @CodyGray. I will read it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you access each [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review) and go to its History tab. There you can find the posts you skipped. If you have less than 10K rep you may need to click on "show skipped reviews" link at the bottom of that page, if you have more than 10K you'll want to click on the "my review history" link instead. You can then click on the Skip link and find out what happened (if anything) to the post.

There's no need therefore for another button.

Be careful though because just because some other random people chose some action for a post doesn't mean they are all right. There's a [guideline for reviewing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing) on the Global Meta.

Comment: I have 3K rep and I see it :) Thanks!